# I have issue and error while running ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework

Here is the error I am getting, Can anyone tell me the fix. I wasted my 4 hours but nothing helped. I was trying to fix this using some of the solution given on stackoverflow, but not getting the exact solution. I am not very good at it as it was my first project and I am trying to run it using a tutorial. but Don't know where is the issue.

```
[npm] > tesTopper@0.0.1 ionic:serve C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper
[npm] > ionic-app-scripts serve "--host=0.0.0.0" "--port=8100"
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
[npm] [23:53:37]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.3
[npm] [23:53:37]  watch started ...
[npm] [23:53:37]  build dev started ...
[npm] [23:53:38]  typescript error
[npm]             Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'esnext', 'dom',
[npm]             'dom.iterable', 'webworker', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core', 'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator',
[npm]             'es2015.iterable', 'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol',
[npm]             'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object', 'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string',
[npm]             'es2017.intl', 'esnext.asynciterable'.
[npm] [23:53:38]  ionic-app-script task: "serve"
[npm] [23:53:38]  TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
[npm] TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
[npm]     at Object.escapeHtml (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\helpers.js:253:10)
[npm]     at generateCodeBlock (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:187:77)
[npm]     at generateDiagnosticHtml (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:179:12)
[npm]     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[npm]     at Object.printDiagnostics (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:15:39)
[npm]     at getTsConfig (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:322:34)
[npm]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:298:46)
[npm]     at step (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:32:23)
[npm]     at Object.next (C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:13:53)
[npm]     at C:\Users\dinka\Documents\ionic\tesTopper\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:7:71
[npm] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[npm] npm ERR! errno 1
[npm] npm ERR! tesTopper@0.0.1 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--host=0.0.0.0" "--port=8100"`
[npm] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[npm] npm ERR!
[npm] npm ERR! Failed at the tesTopper@0.0.1 ionic:serve script.
[npm] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: may need to update  typescript `npm install -g typescript@latest`

Comment: still getting same error